# Terraform: Cloudwatch Log Stream not taking dependencies into account, throws 400 err

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create an [Cloudwatch Log Group](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_log_group.html) and corresponding [Cloudwatch Log Stream](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_log_stream.html) on AWS with Terraform.  Seems very straight forward, however my code is throwing `ResourceNotFoundException: The specified log group does not exist` error in regards to the log group on Plan.

My terraform:

```
variable "firehose_stream_name" {
    default = "streamName"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "firehose_log_group" {
    name = "/aws/kinesisfirehose/${var.firehose_stream_name}"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_stream" "firehose_log_stream" {
    name = "S3Delivery"
    log_group_name = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.firehose_log_group.name}"
    depends_on = ["aws_cloudwatch_log_group.firehose_log_group"]
}
```

Now, one would assume that Terraform would calculate the dependency based on the `name` value of the `firehose_log_group` being in the `log_group_name` of the `aws_cloudwatch_log_stream`.  This is not happening.  With that reference, and with the explicit `depends_on` block, this code is throwing a `ResourceNotFoundException: The specified log group does not exist` error on Plan.  As if it's not able to calculate the dependency between the `aws_cloudwatch_log_group` and the `aws_cloudwatch_log_stream`.  In any other scenario this kind of dependency would be calculated by Terraform.

What is happening here?  Is there some kind of error in the code I'm not seeing? Is there some kind of dependency that Terraform is unable to calculate between these two?

**UPDATE**: 
turns out this works fine on an Ubuntu server with TF version 0.11.3 for Linux, but the error occurs on the version 0.11.3 for Windows.  The plot thickens.

This code is based on the TF documentation: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_log_stream.html

EDIT: explicitly include stream name variable

Comment: Can you show the full error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like aws_cloudwatch_log_group.firehose_log_group.name is not set, before digging more, Can you cross check and confirm whether var.firehose_stream_name is defined!!